# Cannot retrieve value from context provider ami since account/region are not specified at the stack level

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

Hello I have problems when I try to create a stack on AWS CDK

```js
    import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
    import ec2 = require('@aws-cdk/aws-ec2');
    import { SubnetType } from '@aws-cdk/aws-ec2';

    export class FirstDemoStack extends cdk.Stack {
      constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const natGatewayProvider = ec2.NatProvider.instance({
          instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType('t3.micro')
        });

        const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'VPC_Test', {
          cidr: '10.0.0.0/26',
          maxAzs: 1,
          subnetConfiguration:[
            {
              subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
              name: 'Ingress',
              cidrMask: 28
            },
            {
              cidrMask: 28,
              name: 'Application',
              subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE
            }
          ],
          natGatewayProvider,
          natGateways:2,
        });
      }
    }
```

So I get the next error

```sh
    Cannot retrieve value from context provider ami since account/region are not specified at the stack level. Either configure "env" with explicit account and region when you define your stack, or use the environment variables "CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT" and "CDK_DEFAULT_REGION" to inherit environment information from the CLI (not recommended for production stacks)
```

I know that I need to add the region and account to my stack, but I don't know where

Answer (score 6):

If we pick apart the error, it's saying in order to locate the proper AMIs for your EC2 instances, it needs a region/account to be set. There are a few ways to do this.

1) **Recommended** Set the information when you instantiate the stack

In your `index.ts` file, you will find the `new FirstDemoStack(...)` call. You need to modify it to include some environment variables. This is where you can set your account and region.

```
new FirstDemoStack(app, 'first-demo-stack', { env: {
  account: 'your-account-number',
  region: 'us-east-1' // or whatever region you use
}});
```

2) You can set it in your environment variables.

You will need to set `CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT` and `CDK_DEFAULT_REGION` to their respective values. You *can* use this, but if you ever need to use two regions or two accounts, you will need to hard code them.

Comment: hmm I get this error when running unit test, how do we mock this context provider?

Comment: I believe region must always be set to a valid value, but you could likely set a fake account number (possibly in the CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT parameter). This would allow you to unit test without it "actually" set.